# getElementById returning null

Tags: javascript, html

I am having trouble with getElementById returning null. I have tried putting the id directly into it, which works fine.

This function is called by the submit button, it retrieves the names of uploaded files and writes them to hidden fields.

```
function onSubmitting() {
     try {
          var AU = $('#uploader').data('AU');
          var file_list = AU.files; 
          var i = 0;
          while (i < 10) {
              var tempName = "image" + i.toString();
              if (!(typeof file_list[i] === "undefined")) {
                  document.getElementById(tempName).value = "test";
               }  
              i++;
           }                     
       }
       catch (err) {
           alert(err.message);
       }
 }
```

The relevant html is here:

```
 <input type="hidden" name="image1" id="image1" />
 <input type="hidden" name="image2" id="image2" />
 <input type="hidden" name="image3" id="image3" />
 <input type="hidden" name="image4" id="image4" />
 <input type="hidden" name="image5" id="image5" />
 <input type="hidden" name="image6" id="image6" />
 <input type="hidden" name="image7" id="image7" />
 <input type="hidden" name="image8" id="image8" />
 <input type="hidden" name="image9" id="image9" />
 <input type="hidden" name="image10" id="image10" />
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: Instead of naming them like that, use a common class. It'll be much cleaner.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does jQuery or a DOM method such as \`getElementById\` not find the element?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first time through the loop the ID will be `image0` which is not present in your HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Your loop runs from 0 to 9, but your elements are named from 1 to 10. Change

```
for (var i=0; i<10; i++)
```

to

```
for (var i=1; i<=10; i++)
```

or use `(i+1)` everywhere in the loop body

Answer (score 0):

As Bergi and Justin said, you're starting your loop with `i=0`. I've updated it to use `i=1`, and `i <= 10`, and it works as expected :)

See: http://jsfiddle.net/sAKJd/